# Splitting key/value input file in map/reduce task

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a MapReduce task that has the following input file

```
File1    value1
File1    value2
File2    value3
File2    value4
```

The Mapper will access the file name and search for the specific value in it.

Question:
I would like to have an optimization technique to optimize the disk access for these files. I need to assign the same file id to the same mapper. So I can make sure the file will be access by only one task at a time.

Example:
Required

```
Mapper 1: File1 (value1), File1 (value2)
Mapper 2: File2 (value3), File2 (value4)
```

Not required:

```
Mapper 1: File1 (value1), File2 (value3)
Mapper 2: File1 (value2), File2 (value4)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this

```
 File1    value1
 File1    value2
 File2    value3
 File2    value4
```

is written to an existing file

The way to ensure what you want is to sort this input file by the first column(and to store it sorted)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to send specific data to the map tasks without partitioning the input data. Partition the input data as required and use the [TextFileInputFormar.isSplittable()](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#How_do_I_get_each_of_a_job.27s_maps_to_work_on_one_complete_input-file_and_not_allow_the_framework_to_split-up_the_files.3F).

Answer (score 0):

May I humbly suggest that you use the reducer for achieving the effect you want.

Getting all the values for a key into the same task is the very definition of "reduce".

If there is further reduction needed, run another job on the outputs of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

With 2 files in picture, you would definitly have a minimum of 2 map with default TextInputFormat as the hadoop input format.

All you have to do is to create a custom InputFormat extending TextInputFormat and override the **isSplittable()** method to return **false**. In this scenario, one file would be proccessed fully by one mapper and the next file fully by the other.